# Can I continue the for loop from callback inside the loop?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I am using selenium concurrently element checking using timer in `c#`. If element found the call back will call then I need to continue the for loop.
This is my code, it is not working. Any Suggestions?

```cs
for (i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
    //statement
    mycallback((s) => { if(s) continue; }); // continue here
    //statement
}
```

Comment: you want to continue `for` loop from the beginning in some cases and continue the trace in some other cases?

Comment: can you elaborate .i coudn't get it .in this for loop . i used time based approach . so it is difficult .so i use event based . so when i detect some element using callback .if that callback occured the process .will stop and continue to the next index .but this call back working but the loop stoping or continue not working .

Comment: Is this Java or C#? It can't be both...

Comment: c# .I can't  continue the loop .i thought both have same approach.i used system.timer class and thread .in java also this approach possible .

Answer (score 0):

in `C#` you can use `labels` to go where you want.
they transfer the program control directly to a `labeled` statement

look at the snippet below:

```
for (i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
    //statement

    mycallback((s) => { if(s) goto myLabel; });

    // continue here
    myLabel: // parts of your code

    //statement
}
```

it is not recommended though that could be useful in some cases.

more info about this syntax:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto

more discussion about using labels: [Does anyone still use [goto] in C# and if so why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545720/does-anyone-still-use-goto-in-c-sharp-and-if-so-why)

Comment: Thank you for your replay .it showing compile error .showing invalid jump

Comment: It depends on where you put the `label`. as an error example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535283/why-cant-i-add-a-goto-label-at-the-end-of-a-method

Comment: i just add the label outside the callback and goto it works.other wise it showing invalid jump