# C# program to develop a pyramid, using for loop

Tags: c#

Im probably missing something but i cant find a way to solve this simple problem..

im suppost to write a short code asking for a positive integer and then print out a pyramid using FOR statement, f.ex

```
Height: 0
Height: 4
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

Here is the code itself

```
using System; 

namespace starpyramid
{ 
    class program 
    { 
        static void Main() 
        { 
            Veryfy:
            Console.Write("Height: "); 
            int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(i>0)
            {
            goto main;
            }
            else
                {
            goto Verify;
            }   

        main:
            for (int h = 1; h< luku1;h++) // main loop for the lines
                {
                for (int s = 1; s < luku1; s++) //for spaces before the stars
                    {
                        if (s == h)
                        {
                        break;
                        }
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                Console.Write("*\n");
                }
    }   
    } 
}
```

Maybe someone could helpo me solving this

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Oh dear god, **don't use goto statements**. I thought these had been eradicated by now?

Comment: There is absolutely *no* reason to use `goto` here.

Comment: I spy with my little eye, two `goto`s... That's not going to get you a lot of positives. In any case, I believe your issue is that you're only ever writing a single asterisk, and you add too many spaces (you should only print half of `h`).

Comment: You need to tell us what the problem is. Are you getting an error, or is the program doing something you didn't expect?

Comment: Your first label is misspelled, so the program won't compile.

Comment: is `luku1` ever defined anywhere?

Comment: Programming homeworks. Feels as if it was just yesterday. :)

Comment: What `luku1` stands for and where do you define it?

Comment: [this'll tell you what to do](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/10217/creating-pyramid-in-C-Sharp.aspx)

Comment: Ignoring the `goto`s (just put the target code inside the `if` and `else`), inside your outer loop, you need to determine how many spaces and how many stars to print. That's just arithmetic, and not what you're asking about, so I assume you can do it. After you know how many of each, you need two `for` loops inside the big one: One to print the spaces, and one to print the stars. (You could do both in one loop, but there's no reason for it.)

Comment: [Here's a freebie if you can translate it](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez9we/)

Comment: [why you shouldn't use goto's](http://www.dotnettoad.com/index.php?/archives/20-when-not-to-use-the-goto-keyword.html) & [when you may use them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545720/does-anyone-still-use-goto-in-c-sharp-and-if-so-why) though I kinda feel the answer should be never ever ever (the raptors will get you....)

Comment: Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/Romoku/9808698) for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its work perfect,

```
using System; 

namespace starpyramid
{ 
    class program 
    { 
        static void Main() 
        { 
            Console.Write("Height: "); 
            int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(i>0)
            {
            goto main;
            }
            else
            {
                Main();
            }   

            main:
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int h = 1; h<= i;h++) // main loop for the lines
            {
                for (int s = h; s <= i; s++) //for spaces before the stars
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                for(int j=1; j<(h*2); j=j+2)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
            Console.Write("\n");
            }
    }   
    } 
}
```

but without goto program also work see,

```
using System; 

namespace starpyramid
{ 
    class program 
    { 
        static void Main() 
        { 
            Console.Write("Height: "); 
            int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int h = 1; h<= i;h++) // main loop for the lines
            {
                for (int s = h; s <= i; s++) //for spaces before the stars
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                for(int j=1; j<(h*2); j=j+2)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
            Console.Write("\n");
            }
    }   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for bad example of mine but Ajay Patel got it! It does a pyramide but the stars should grow like 1 3 5 7 etc without the spaces between. Like in the example i posted in my first post

Comment: If i was the one grading the work i would lower the score just based on the use of "goto". No matter if the program works or not :)

Comment: @Sandman, I think I would just hand it back to the student and tell them to do it again without using goto. - haha

Comment: ya i devlop above code without goto statement bt he require goto in his code so i mention it.

Comment: i edit my code see this.