# How to check if a key is being pressed in c# (console app)

Tags: c#, audio, key

So i`m trying to create a piano game. where specific keys act like the piano keys.For example:
if "A" is being pressed playback audio file for note C
if "s" is being pressed playback audio file for note D and so on.
I wrote this:

```
piano:         
 if (pressedKey.Key == ConsoleKey.A) ;
             {
                 Console.Beep();


                 {
                     goto piano;
```

the beep will be replaced with the audio file this is just for testing.
So when the program reaches this piece of code and i hit "a" it starts beeping  over and over and it wont stop until the program is closed. I want it to beep once every time I hit "A". How do I achieve this?
Sorry for the dumb question and bad English.

Comment: How do you fill your "pressedKey" variable ?

Comment: You have VERY little code here, but you appear to be causing an infinite loop as soon as you press the 'A' key.
You're hitting the A key, which returns to piano, which remembers the old key, because you never checked again.  
Btw, `goto` is evil. :)

Comment: Are there even any legitimate uses for `goto`?

Comment: @redFIVE it seems so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545720/does-anyone-still-use-goto-in-c-sharp-and-if-so-why

Comment: @rene those are all pretty weak arguments for its usefulness, in my opinion

Comment: `I think my eyes just got sick`, don't use `goto` in C# code this is not `COBOL`

Comment: I'm more with [this outcome](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2486630/578411)  @redFIVE

Comment: haha I havent seen that one yet @rene

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like you want to play some sound on **key pressing** in console application, This is how you are gonna Do that!

```
public static void PressAnyKey()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stroke Keys!");
    do
    {
        var mykey = Console.ReadKey(true); //Read The Key

        switch (mykey.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                Console.WriteLine("UpArrow Pressed");
                //do your stuff
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                Console.WriteLine("DownArrow Pressed");
                //do your stuff
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                Console.WriteLine("RightArrow Pressed");
                //do your stuff
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                Console.WriteLine("LeftArrow Pressed");
                //do your stuff
                break;
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

and if you want to emit some sound from system speaker you can use `Console.Beep(Frequency,Duration)` Method and `int Frequency` & `int Duration` variables to adjust it's Frequency and Duration!

 this is how the Function will be after adding few lines!

```
public static void BeepOnKey()
{
    int frequency = 10000;
    int duration = 100;

    Console.WriteLine("Use keyboard arrows to adjust frequency and duration");
    do
    {
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            Console.Beep(frequency, duration);
            //this method emits beep sound from system speakers
        }

        var mykey = Console.ReadKey(true); //Read The Key

        switch (mykey.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                Console.WriteLine("UpArrow Pressed");
                frequency += 100;
                frequency = Math.Min(frequency, 15000);
                //do your stuff
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                Console.WriteLine("DownArrow Pressed");
                frequency -= 100;
                frequency = Math.Max(frequency, 1000);
                //do your stuff
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                Console.WriteLine("RightArrow Pressed");
                duration += 100;
                duration = Math.Min(duration, 1000);
                //do your stuff
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                Console.WriteLine("LeftArrow Pressed");
                duration -= 100;
                duration = Math.Max(duration, 100);
                //do your stuff
                break;
        }
    } while (true);
}
```